# Redirect After AJAX Request even though Headers and Data Attributes are passed correctly with Python3

Tags: ajax, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

On a government site I managed to login via my credidentials (specified as a python dictonary in `login_data`) as follows:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https:......../login'
    r = s.get(url, data=login_data, headers=headers, verify=False)
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers = headers, verify=False)
    print(r.content)
```

which displays a html:

`b'<!DOCTYPE html.....` and if I search for my username i find `<span class="rich-messages-label msg-def-inf-label">Welcome, USER..XYZ!<` From which i conclude a succesful login.

Next I want to proceed to **the search subsite** (`url = 'https:......./search`) of the site I'm now logged in to. This subsite allows me to search the government records for an incident (`incident-ID`) on a given date (`start_date`, `end_date`).

because of the login success I tried the following:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https:......../search'
    r = s.get(url, data=search_data, headers=headers, verify=False)
    r = s.post(url, data=search_data, headers = headers, verify=False)
    print(r.content)
```

In advance i defined search_data using *Google Chrome Inspecor* for *Network* and *Header*:

```
search_data:{
    'AJAXREQUEST': '_viewRoot',
    'theSearchForm': 'theSearchForm',
    'incident-ID' : '12345',
    'start_date' : '05/03/2019 00:00:00 +01:00',
    'end_date' : '05/03/2019 23:59:59 +01:00',
}
```

and i specified headers to include more than just the agent:

```
 headers = { 
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=8351xxxxxxxxxxxxFD5; _ga=GA1.2.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx',
    'Host': 'somehost...xyz.eu',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
}
```

So far the setup should be nice, no? But I ran into a problem as the `print(r.content)` doesn't give me the .html as after the login but some disappointingly short: `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta name="Ajax-Response" content="redirect" /><meta name="Location" content="home.seam?cid=3774801" /></head></html>`

it's a pitty because I can see in the inspctor that the response for the post-request in the browser yields the exact data I am looking for. Similarl the first post-request yields the exact same data as my python command `r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers = headers, verify=False)`. But the `print(r.content)` as already said seams to be a redirect which only brings me back to the login site, stating *you're already logged in*.

To sum up:

- The first `request.Session.get` & `-.post` worked (I get the same response html as in the Google Chrome Inspector).
- The second `request.Session.post` doesnt work as it just yields some weird redirect (but I get
  the correct response in the Google Chrome Inspector).

What am I missing??? Please Help! :S

Comment: You need a single request, either GET or POST, not both `r = s.get(...)` and `r = s.post(...)`. The node `meta` with `Location` name clearly states that there is a redirection. Try to allow redirects `s.post(url, data=search_data, headers = headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)`

Comment: in the second instant yes. But the first needs both in order to verify the login. Allowing for redirects doesn't work, as it still gives me the same output for `print(r.content)`

Comment: In your headers you have set a Cookie and that may override the cookies stored by the session and change the server's response. Usually it's not required to modify the headers, except to change the User-Agent in some cases.

Comment: I also tried this before and it doesn't have any effect whatsoever. Unfortunately I still get the response "Location" *redirect", which clearly is wrong (abnormal) behavior if compared to the what is shown in the Google Chrome Inspector for the same request. 

I wished I'd just get this darn html I =( don't understand what the missing part is. I mean fetching the response with r.content is not wrong, right? what is missing in the request? Could it be that i'm not using the same session id? or the server somehow detects that I have skiped a few intermediate steps?